# Incorrect column name "", 1166 during CSV import

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am trying to import a csv file into MySQL 5.6 using Workbench 6.3, using the Table Data Import wizard.  I had a few issues with illegal characters which I fixed by doing a search and replace on the headers in excel, but now I am getting the following error -

`DBError: ("Incorrect column name ''", 1166)
ERROR: Import data file: ("Incorrect column name ''", 1166)`

When I am trying to import it, it seems like MySQL thinks there's a column where there isn't one - [image]

This is what I suspect is causing the issue, but unchecking it doesn't help.

In the raw csv file, the headers column, it lookes like
`...Quantity_Needed, Part_Number,`.

Is it the last comma after Part_Number that is making MySQL do this?  In the errors before it gave me the column name that was problematic but with this I don't know what to fix.

Edit:  Fixed it.  Tried re-exporting again without the second duplicate column from the get go instead of trying to fix it, and it worked.   I'm thinking maybe there was some bad data in that column or something.

Comment: Quick guess: Your CSV file has a backtick in it (`\``)

Comment: Just did a full search and replace and couldn't find a single back tick.

Comment: In the table data import wizard is there a 'lines terminated by' input. I've had weird issues and had to do either *\r* or *\n* or *\r\n* depending on where the file originated from, for example, Mac vs Windows.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be an option in MySQL Workbench 6.3, all I can set is Line Separator t LF, CR, or CR LF, Enclose Strings In set to " and Field Separator set to ,.   Might it be worth it to update workbench to a higher version?

Comment: I tried re-exporting the csv file from SAGE 50, the only issue was two columns with the same name, and instead of deleting the second one this time, I renamed it.  However, that only fixed that issue and the 'blank' column I had before, but now I am still getting the same error.